# Angular 8 - Getting Runtime compiler not loaded error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lazy-loading

I need to dynamically create lazy loaded routes. When I use import syntax, e.g. `` loadChildren: () => import(`./pages/${module.moduleName}/${module.moduleName}.module`).then(m => m[childModuleName]), `` it works on JIT but when running on AOT, it throws this error:
`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded` as per https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10582 the solution would be to use the old string syntax:
```` loadChildren: `./pages/${module.moduleName/${module.moduleName}.module#${childModuleName}`,

````
I get this error: 
``` ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './pages/client-migration/client-migration.module.ngfactory' ```
````

Answer (score 0):

import the module name into your module.ts.